# Как можно улучшить код? Стек - задача на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, инспекция-кода, стек

*У меня есть код, хотел бы узнать, как можно его ускорить, упростить(сделать красивее :)), сделать так, чтобы он кушал меньше памяти и вообще, возможно ли это сделать?*

*На данный момент у меня такие результаты: Время - 91 мс | Память - 3.98Mb | Python 3.7.3*

---

Гоша реализовал структуру данных Дек, максимальный размер которого определяется заданным числом. Методы `push_back(x)`, `push_front(x)`, `pop_back()`, `pop_front()` работали корректно. Но, если в деке было много элементов, программа работала очень долго. Дело в том, что не все операции выполнялись за O(1). Помогите Гоше! Напишите эффективную реализацию.
**Внимание: при реализации нельзя использовать связный список.**

---

***Формат ввода***

В первой строке записано количество команд n — целое число, не превосходящее 5000. Во второй строке записано число `m` — максимальный размер дека. Он не превосходит 1000. В следующих n строках записана одна из команд:

`push_back(value)` – добавить элемент в конец дека. Если в деке уже находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».

`push_front(value)` – добавить элемент в начало дека. Если в деке уже находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».

`pop_front()` – вывести первый элемент дека и удалить его. Если дек был пуст, то вывести «error».

`pop_back()` – вывести последний элемент дека и удалить его. Если дек был пуст, то вывести «error».

`Value` — целое число, по модулю не превосходящее 1000.
Формат вывода

Выведите результат выполнения каждой команды на отдельной строке. Для успешных запросов `push_back(x)` и `push_front(x)` ничего выводить не надо.

---

***Формат вывода***

Выведите результат выполнения каждой команды на отдельной строке. Для успешных запросов `push_back(x)` и `push_front(x)` ничего выводить не надо.

---

**Пример 1:**

Ввод:

```
4
4
push_front 861
push_front -819
pop_back
pop_back
```

Вывод:

```
861
-819
```

**Пример 2:**

Ввод:

```
7
10
push_front -855
push_front 720
pop_back
pop_back
push_back 844
pop_back
push_back 823
```

Вывод:

```
-855
720
844
```

**Пример 3:**

Ввод:

```
6
6
push_front -201
push_back 959
push_back 102
push_front 20
pop_front
pop_back
```

Вывод:

```
20
102
```

---

Мой код:

```
class Dek:
    def __init__(self, max_size: int):
        self._elements = [None] * max_size
        self._max_size = max_size
        self._head = 0
        self._tail = 0
        self._size = 0

    def is_empty(self):
        return self._size == 0

    def push_back(self, value: int):
        if self._size != self._max_size:
            self._elements[self._tail] = value
            self._tail = (self._tail + 1) % self._max_size
            self._size += 1
        else:
            raise OverflowError

    def push_front(self, value: int):
        if self._size != self._max_size:
            self._elements[self._head - 1] = value
            self._head = (self._head - 1) % self._max_size
            self._size += 1
        else:
            raise OverflowError

    def pop_back(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IndexError
        x = self._elements[self._tail - 1]
        self._elements[self._tail - 1] = None
        self._tail = (self._tail - 1) % self._max_size
        self._size -= 1
        return x

    def pop_front(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IndexError
        x = self._elements[self._head]
        self._elements[self._head] = None
        self._head = (self._head + 1) % self._max_size
        self._size -= 1
        return x


def main():
    count_command = int(input())
    queue_size = int(input())

    queue = Dek(queue_size)
    commands = {
        'push_front': queue.push_front,
        'push_back': queue.push_back,
        'pop_front': queue.pop_front,
        'pop_back': queue.pop_back,
    }
    for i in range(count_command):
        command = input()
        operation, *value = command.split()
        if value:
            try:
                result = commands[operation](int(*value))
                if result is not None:
                    print(result)
            except OverflowError:
                print('error')
        else:
            try:
                result = commands[operation]()
                print(result)
            except IndexError:
                print('error')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код хорош. Он отвечает всем требованиям задачи, простых способов улучшить производительность или уменьшить требуемую память я не вижу. Его можно записать короче, но при этом он станет работать немного дольше. Функцию `main` можно записать проще, но задание касается в большей степени класса `Dek`. Посмотрите на вариант ниже, но, ещё раз повторюсь, он не лучше и не хуже вашего:

```
class Dek:
    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self._data = [None] * max_size
        self._front = max_size - 1
        self._back = 0
        self._size = 0

    def is_empty(self):
        return self._size == 0

    def push_back(self, value):
        self._back = self._push(self._back, 1, value)

    def pop_back(self):
        self._back, value = self._pop(self._back, 1)
        return value

    def push_front(self, value):
        self._front = self._push(self._front, -1, value)

    def pop_front(self):
        self._front, value = self._pop(self._front, -1)
        return value

    def _push(self, i, di, value):
        if self._size >= len(self._data):
            raise OverflowError
        self._data[i] = value
        self._size += 1
        return (i + di) % len(self._data)

    def _pop(self, i, di):
        if self._size <= 0:
            raise IndexError
        j = (i - di) % len(self._data)
        x = self._data[j]
        self._data[j] = None
        self._size -= 1
        return j, x
 

def main():
    count_command = int(input())
    queue_size = int(input())

    queue = Dek(queue_size)
    for _ in range(count_command):
        verb, *values = input().split()
        op = getattr(queue, verb)
        values = tuple(map(int, values))
        try:
            result = op(*values)
        except (IndexError, OverflowError):
            result = 'error'
        if result is not None:
            print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```